# unknown struct error in function C - Linux

Tags: c, struct

I got a little problem.. I wrote a C program in linux that have a struct and a function that gets the struct and the program worked great in one file but when I split it to 2 files (main.c function.c), I've got an error that say that the struct that I use in the function is unknown. Do I need to declare in any way about the struct in the second file?
Thanks:)

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you're doing it now?

Comment: Yes, you have to use the preprocessor command `include`, but it would be better if you put part of the code of each file and their names, then we could give you more details on what to do.

Comment: You need to post the relevant parts of your code, or all any of us can do is **just guess** as what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

you can define the struct in function.h ,in main.c and function.c add this `#include"function.h"`

the function.h Format like this

```
#ifndef FUNCTION_H
#define FUNCTION_H
struct some_struct{

}struct_name;
#endif
```

Comment: @dvir naim - this is your answer: 1) Move your struct definition into a separate header (.h) file.  2) #include the header in every .c file that uses the struct.  3) Make sure add a "guard" (#ifndef MYHEADER_H/#define MYHEADER_H/#endif) around your header contents.  And be sure to upvote and accept pang1567's response.